# Graph csv data that is represented horizontally rather than vertical - Python Pandas CSV

Tags: pandas, csv

Context: I have combined numerous CSV's into one representing use case vs usage over a period of time. 
The way the data is represented currently is attached.

[image]

**What I am trying to do is, for each usecase, graph across row A(1, 1.1, 1.9, 4.0.11435, 4.1.11436 and so on...) - creating a linear plot to show progression over time**

What I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plot_df = pd.read_csv("results.csv")

milestones = plot_df.columns[1:]

row = plot_df.iloc[0]
row.plot(kind='line')
plt.show()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: @ScottBoston Where would this line go?

Comment: Getting "TypeError: no numeric data to plot". Wondering if the numerics have to be converted to int?

Comment: Try `plot_pot.set_index('usecase').T.plot()` after read_csv line

Comment: Gets me closer to no error upon build but see no plot.                                                                                      
        plot_df = pd.read_csv("results.csv")
        plot_df.set_index('UseCase').T.plot()

Comment: You still ned plt.show()

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks for you prompt responses. I can run with this! I think I need to clean up some data but I will post back once it is a little cleaner to see.

Answer (score 0):

import the panda library.
in your code you called for the pd but the library itself i not imported
, your code will be like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plot_df = pd.read_csv("results.csv")

milestones = plot_df.columns[1:]

row = plot_df.iloc[0]
row.plot(kind='line')
plt.show()
```